# Inject property into autowired class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

Using Roo, and I've got a property called 'imagesBaseDir' in a property file called app.properties, and *should* be getting picked up by this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>
```

I want to push this property into a controller, so I've put a field in there like this (as per all the examples I have read)

```
private @Value("${imagesBaseDir}") String imageBaseDir;
```

But it's not getting set.

Tried it with other properties from e.g. db.properties, which I know Spring is definitely picking up, so my props file is probably ok.

What am I missing? Driving me nuts, all the examples looks so straightforward but it's just not working for me :(

Thanks!

Comment: is there spring-mvc invovled, and how? What value is actually set? is your object a bean?

Comment: It's just set to null when I run the code. Yep, I'm using spring-mvc, it's basically a standard Roo project. I've tried putting @Autowired above the field too, and I get nothing

Comment: is the above code in a @Controller?

Comment: Yep, it's in an @Controller (one that I added via Roo - 'add controller'). After you mentioned spring-mvc I wondered if it would be able to read the i18n properties, but nope. In fact, in all cases, it's not actually evaluating the expression, so the value is actually being set to the string "imagesBaseDir" or whatever I specify as the property name. It's not being evaluated - i think thats the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having a child context (dispatcher-servlet.xml) and you are trying to inject the value in a controller that's defined there. However, child contexts don't get the properties resolved with `<context:prop...`. You need to have that in dispatcher-servlet.xml as well.

Comment: It works, thanks a million. Won't make that mistake again haha. Yep, I copied this line "<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>" from the application-context.xml file to the webmvc-config.xml and it all works great now - cheers